# Adding a summary report and disk information to VB Script

Tags: windows, vbscript

I was hoping someone could help me with this code. I wanted to add two things to this script but can't seem to get it working at all.

The script works fine but what isn't working is trying to add the disk information and trying to create a summary report for total size of disk.

at the end of it I'm trying to make an output of what

```
wmic diskdrive list brief /format:list
```

would give you.

something like this:

```
Caption=WDC WD2500BEKT-75PVMT1
DeviceID=\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
Model=WDC WD2500BEKT-75PVMT1
Partitions=1
Size=250056737280
```

Here is the script so far

```
Option Explicit

const strComputer = "."
const strReport = "c:\path\to\file"


Dim objWMIService, objItem, colItems 
Dim strDriveType, strDiskSize, txt

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE        DriveType=3")
txt = "Drive" & vbtab & "Size" & vbtab & "Used" & vbtab & "Free" & vbtab & "Free(%)" & vbcrlf
For Each objItem in colItems

DIM pctFreeSpace,strFreeSpace,strusedSpace

pctFreeSpace = INT((objItem.FreeSpace / objItem.Size) * 1000)/10
strDiskSize = Int(objItem.Size /1073741824) & "Gb"
strFreeSpace = Int(objItem.FreeSpace /1073741824) & "Gb"
strUsedSpace = Int((objItem.Size-objItem.FreeSpace)/1073741824) & "Gb"
txt = txt & objItem.Name & vbtab & strDiskSize & vbtab & strUsedSpace & vbTab & strFreeSpace & vbtab & pctFreeSpace & vbcrlf

Next

writeTextFile txt, strReport
wscript.echo "Report written to " & strReport & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & txt

' Procedure to write output to a text file
private sub writeTextFile(byval txt,byval strTextFilePath)
Dim objFSO,objTextFile

set objFSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

set objTextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strTextFilePath)

objTextFile.Write(txt)

objTextFile.Close
SET objTextFile = nothing
end sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The `wmic` call and your script do entirely different things. The former queries the [`Win32_DiskDrive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132) class to gather information about the *physical disks*, whereas the latter queries the [`Win32_LogicalDisk`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173) class to gather information about the *volumes*.

You can reproduce the output of the `wmic` command with something like this:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
For Each disk In wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive")
  WScript.Echo "Caption=" & disk.Caption & vbNewLine _
    & "DeviceID=" & disk.DeviceID & vbNewLine _
    & "Model=" & disk.Model & vbNewLine _
    & "Partitions=" & disk.Partitions & vbNewLine _
    & "Size=" & disk.Size
Next
```

However, the size returned by this query is the raw capacity of the physical disk. At this level you can't distinguish if a block is "free" or "used". Those are concepts that apply to filesystems. On that level, a sector either does or doesn't contain one or more files or file fragments. It's "free" when it doesn't contain any file and "used" otherwise. On that level, you don't get any information about "partitions", though, because those exist on a lower level (partitions contain filesystems).

What you need to do is decide which information you actually want to report, and then choose the appropriate properties from the relevant WMI class(es).